# SAN device storage config for SQL 2008 cluster

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, storage, storage-area-network

Windows Server 2008 R2 (clustered active/passive) - SQL Server 2008 Enterprise - Dell MD3200i PowerVault SAN

8 x 450GB 15k SAS drives (RAID 10)

What is the best stripe unit size for this configuration (for optimum SQL performance)?

I am reading conflicting reports of 64k, 128k or 256k.

Please help! Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [SAN device storage config for SQL 2008 cluster](http://serverfault.com/questions/274527/san-device-storage-config-for-sql-2008-cluster)

Comment: @Zack I have the same storage, did you Install the Dell MD Storage Manager already? I had problems after the installation, the shortcuts did not appear properly, and the Storage Manager utility .exe didn't have any names on the program files folder.

Comment: Yes, the Dell management software installed fine for me.

Comment: @Zack In my case the install was also fine, however if you check you "C:\Program Files (x86)\Dell\MD Storage Software\MD Storage Manager\client" directory there was a .exe file without a name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you read this Microsoft [article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd758814%28SQL.100%29.aspx)?  Due to the nature of each vendors san they will also be a valuable resource for stripe size, as them for their test results.  I recieved an extensive white paper from Dell when I install one of their sans.

After formatting the san and prior to installing SQL you should run SQLIO and test the performance.  The formatting could be repeated with a different allocation size and the testing repeated.  Although repeated formatting and testing will take some time you will only have ONE chance in getting this correct unless you want to bring down your production site to reformat your disk subsystem.